# Is the maximum of derivatives of a function in (s,2)-Sobolev space (an RKHS) bounded by their norms?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $f(x) \in W^{s,2}(\Omega) \equiv H^s$, where $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$, $s > d/2$ and $W^{s,2}$ is a $(s,2)$-Sobolev space. Clearly, $W^{s,2}$ is an Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space (RKHS) and therefore $|f(x)| \le M\left\|f\right\|_{H^s}$ for $M > 0$ holds.

The question is: does this also hold for derivatives of $f$ (they're in $L^2(\Omega)$, but does $|\nabla_x f(x)| \le M'\left\|\nabla_x f\right\|_{L^2}$ hold for some $M' > 0$?)?

Thank you

**Update**

Following @NateEldredge counter-example, if we tighten the requirements s.t. $s \ge 2$ then it'd seem that a bound on $|\nabla_x f(x)|$ in terms of norms does exist, albeit with a different norm.

Consider the case $d = 1$. As stated above, we assume that $f \in H^s(\Omega)$ and $s > d/2$. By requiring that $s \ge 2$, it follows that $g(x) \equiv f'(x) \in H^{s-1}(\Omega)$. Therefore, $g(x)$ is in an RKHS (albeit a different from $f(x)$'s one). Thus, $|g(x)| = |f'(x)| \le M_g \left\| f' \right\|_{H^{s-1}(\Omega)}, M_g>0$.

A $H^s$ norm verifies $\left\| f \right\|_{H^s}^2 \doteq \sum_{|\alpha|_1 \le s} \left\| D^\alpha f \right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}^2$. Therefore,
$$
|f'(x)|^2 \le M_g^2(\left\|f'\right\|_{L^2}^2 + \left\|f''\right\|_{L^2}^2) \\
$$

This process can be used with any $s \ge 2$.

Is this reasoning correct?

Thx

Comment: Many things are not clear: what is a RKHS? If $f$ is a fixed function, where a linear operator appears? Is $x$ fixed? Please, edit.

Comment: RKHS - Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space; $f$ is not fixed, but has an argument $x$;
$x \in \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$

Comment: $x\mapsto f(x)$ is not linear. I do not understand what you are talking about.

Comment: Fixed the question. $f$ is **not** bounded, the evaluation functional is. But I'm asking about the **implication** of it being one - does this hold for **derivatives** of $f$ too?

Comment: I think you need $s > d/2$ in order to have an RKHS; otherwise the elements of $H^s$ are not continuous and evaluation at a point is not well-defined and does not give a bounded functional.

Comment: But I think your question has an immediate counterexample: take $d=1$, $\Omega=(0,1)$, $s=1$.  Then $f'$ can be any $L^2$ function, but clearly you cannot control the pointwise values of an $L^2$ function in terms of its $L^2$ norm (they are not even well defined).

Comment: @NateEldredge OK, I've seen such a requirement ($s > d/2$), e.g. in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.02568.pdf. I can live with it. The question still stands though when the restriction is imposed.

Comment: In your last sentence, can you clarify what norm you want to apply to $\nabla_x f$?

Comment: @NateEldredge I'd say $L^2$?

Comment: I think that you may want to study the standard Sobolev inequalities and embedding theorems, as they give clear answers as to exactly what results of this kind are true.  For example, they indicate why $s>d/2$ is necessary to get a RKHS. They are essentially the first thing that anybody working with Sobolev spaces needs to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $d=1$, $s=1$, $\Omega=(-1,1) \subset \mathbb{R}^1$.  We can find a function $g \in L^2(-1,1)$ (or even continuous) for which $g(0)$ is arbitrarily large but $\|g\|_{L^2(-1,1)}$ is arbitrarily small.  Set $f(x) = \int_{-1}^x g(t)\,dt$; then clearly $f \in H^1(-1,1)$ with $f'=g$, and we can violate any proposed bound of the form $|f'(0)| \le M' \|f'\|_{L^2(-1,1)}$.

Comment: Thx. A question: Does this change if $s > d/2$?

Comment: @qwer1304: My example does have $s>d/2$.  You can modify it to use $s$ as large as you wish, if you take $g$ to be a smooth function instead.

Comment: OK, clearly this cannot work with $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{L^2}$ since $L^2$ is **not** an RKHS. Can some reasonable norm be defined s.t. the bound does work?

Comment: I think that you will have an inequality like $|\partial^\alpha f(x)| \le M'(x, \alpha) \|f\|_{H^s}$ under an assumption like $s > \frac{p}{2} + |\alpha|$.  Again, it would come from classical Sobolev inequalities.